# Get current target of event in document.on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling

I'm currently facing the following problem. On my website, the user has the ability to delete his own entry. When the delete button has been pressed an Ajax call is being made. New content gets delivered and the container fills up with new entries. 
I first empty the container and then fill it with new content. When I empty the container I lose all events on all the buttons that are within one entry. To fix this problem I use the following code

```
$(document).on('click', '.DeleteButton', function (event: Event) { ... });
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that when I access the currenttarget of the event, it delivers me the whole document. I need the currenttarget to first know which button has been pressed and secondly get the ID in the button.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you provide a more specific code?

Comment: jQuery sets `event.currentTarget` appropriately (e.g., to the `.DeleteButton` element) when calling your handler. Can you update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button)? [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 1):

Within that event handler callback, `this` will refer to the `.DeleteButton` element that was clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', '.DeleteButton', function (event: Event) {
    // Use `this` here, for instance `this.id` to get the ID of the `.DeleteButton`
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.DeleteButton', function (event/*: Event*/) {
    console.log("Clicked:", this.id);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" class="DeleteButton" value="One">
  <input type="button" id="btn2" class="DeleteButton" value="Two">
  <input type="button" id="btn3" class="DeleteButton" value="Three">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmmm....but you've said you're using `currentTarget`, and jQuery sets *that* to the `.DeleteButton` element, too.

Comment: You are right I am using `currentTarget` but for some reason jQuery delivers the WHOLE document.

Comment: @Vins - Please see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609165/get-current-target-of-event-in-document-on-function/53609216?noredirect=1#comment94079721_53609165). Separately: Does `this` work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.DeleteButton').on('click', event => {
  const clickedElement = $(event.target);
  const targetElement = clickedElement.closest('.DeleteButton');

  this.delete(targetElement.data('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Funnily enough, `this` did not work. Right now, my code looks like this.

```
$(document).on("click", '.DeleteButton', DeleteButtonHandler.bind(this));
```

I didn't put this code snippet in the question which was dumb from my side. It seems to me that `this` does not work here. However I found a solution to this. Instead of using `event.currentTarget` I am now using `event.target`. This delivers me the correct button with its data in it. I don't even know why. If someone has any explanation to this please explain it to me.